# Python 3.x Изменение значений элементов строки в цикле

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как изменить значение символа строки в цикле? Код:

```
def getDateTimePostfix():
    import datetime;
    dtValue = datetime.datetime.now();
    retValue = str(dtValue);
    for sym in retValue:
        if sym == ':':
            sym = '.'
    return retValue;
```

Пытаюсь скорректировать дату, избавившись от ":", но не получается изменить отдельные символы.

Или лучше сделать цикл такого типа?

```
    i = 0;
    for item in retValue:
        if retValue[i]  == ':':
            retValue[i] = '.'
        i = i + 1;
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
'2016-02-02 13:58:05.235192'.replace(':', '.')
'2016-02-02 13.58.05.235192'
```

А вообще вам стоит посмотреть в сторону метода [`strftime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime)

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо Павел.

Answer (score 5):

Правильный ответ в Вашем случае получает нужную строку напрямую, например, [используя `strftime()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) как [@Pavel Karateev предложил](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/488351/23044):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import time

print(time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H.%M.%S'))
```

Или, если нужны доли секунды:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from datetime import datetime

print(datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H.%M.%S.%f'))
```

---

#### Ответ на вопрос в заголовке

> **Q:** Изменение значений элементов строки в цикле

Строки неизменяемы (immutable) в Питоне. Поэтому изменить строку нельзя, можно только новую создать и заменить старую строчку: `s = create_new_string(s)`.

Бесполезно присваивать новое значение переменной цикла. Оно будет перезаписано на следующей итерации. Если решение нельзя найти используя методы строк (такие как `.replace()`) или используя регулярные выражения (`re` модуль), то вариант с преобразованием в список и использованием `''.join` в конце не так уж и плох. Например, чтобы преобразовать каждый `n`-ый символ в строке в заглавный (начиная с единички), не используя regex:

```
def upper_every_nth(string, n):
    chars = [char if i % n else char.upper()
             for i, char in enumerate(string, start=1)]
    return type(string)().join(chars)
```

Чтобы сделать каждый второй символ заглавным:

```
>>> upper_every_nth('abcde', 2)
'aBcDe'
```

---

#### Замечания по коду в вопросе

- не нужно использовать `;` в конце каждой строки в Питоне
- не нужно помещать `import` внутри функций, если вы твёрдо не знаете зачем это нужно. Помещайте `import` наверху исходного кода модуля
- не используйте локальное время без указания временной зоны (часового пояса), за исключением случая когда вы сразу отображаете пользователю это значение.

Если у вас есть объект, то старайтесь использовать его методы и атрибуты, чтобы получить результат, а не манипулирование его текстового представления. Например: не нужно вызывать `str(dtValue)`, а потом пытаться изменить эту строку, чтобы получить нужный формат (или хуже: пытаться преобразовать эту строку в какой-либо другой объект), лучше сразу вызовите `dtValue.strftime()`, используя формат, приведённый выше. То есть не используйте:

```
# XXX НЕ ДЕЛАЙТЕ ЭТОГО
объект -> его строковое представление -> какие-то строковые
  манипуляции -> попытка распознать получившуюся строку, чтобы создать новый объект
```

Иногда это называют ["Yo-Yo code"](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/260710/1985) (название от [yoyo игрушки произошло](http://giphy.com/gifs/fail-pain-yoyo-KYXWGxC3gcCpq)). Подобный код следует следует избегать. Вместо этого делайте так:

```
объект -> код, который использует методы, атрибуты объекта, 
  чтобы создать новый объект напрямую
```

Следуйте [PEP-8](http://pep8.ru/doc/pep8/) при создании имён, если у вас нет убедительных причин этого не делать, например используйте `get_datetime_postfix()` вместо `getDateTimePostfix()` для имён функций.

Comment: Спасибо Вам, мне очень понравился Ваш ответ!