# считать значения переменных в словарь из строки вида: "key1=value1 key2=value2 key3=value3"

Tags: python

Вводится строка виде `"a=1 b=2 c=3"`. Необходимо считать значение переменных `а,b,c` в эти переменных. Проблема в том, что эти значения могут быть вперемешку(Не `a,b,c`, а `b,a,c`). Желательно, сохранить вообще всё это в словарь, но сойдёт и в переменные

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Creating dictionary from space separated key=value string in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4764547/4279) (несколько более сложный случай)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот записывает в словарь с ключами 'a', 'b' и 'c' и соответствующими им значениями:

```
d = {i.split('=')[0]: int(i.split('=')[1]) for i in input().split(' ')}
print(d)
```

Или вот так:

```
d = {}
for i in input().split(' '):
    spl = i.split('=')
    d[spl[0]] = int(spl[1])
print(d)
```

Comment: можно упростить до: `dict(kv.split('=') for kv in "a=1 b=2 c=3".split())` если не нужно в `int` преобразовывать. А если нужно, то чтобы дважды `split('=')` не вызывать, можно хак употребить: `{k: int(v) for kv in s.split() for k, v in [kv.split('=')]}`. Используйте: `key, value = pair.split('=')` $ `d[key] = int(value)` вместо `spl = i.split('=')` $
   `d[spl[0]] = int(spl[1])`

Answer (score 2):

Можно воспользоваться [ast.literal_eval()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) и [re.findall()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall):

```
import re
import ast

s = 'a=1 b="2" c=3.123 d=[1, 2, 3] e={"Key1":"Val1", "Key2":"Val2"} f=0'
print('исходная строка')
print(s)

# избавляемся от пробелов после запятой
s = re.sub(r',\s+', ',', s)
print('строка без лишних пробелов')
print(s)

d = ast.literal_eval(
    '{'
    + ','.join(['"{0[0]}":{0[1]}'.format(t)
                for t in re.findall(r'([^\s]*)=([^\s]*)', s)])
    + '}'
)
print('результат')
print(d)
```

Вывод (я слегка отформатировал вывод, для красоты):

```
исходная строка
a=1 b="2" c=3.123 d=[1, 2, 3] e={"Key1":"Val1", "Key2":"Val2"} f=0

строка без лишних пробелов
a=1 b="2" c=3.123 d=[1,2,3] e={"Key1":"Val1","Key2":"Val2"} f=0

результат
{'a': 1,
 'b': '2',
 'c': 3.123,
 'd': [1, 2, 3],
 'e': {'Key1': 'Val1', 'Key2': 'Val2'},
 'f': 0}
```

Преимущество данного метода в том, что он поддерживает практически любые встроенные типы переменных:

Comment: Вопрос не требует поддержки произвольных Питон-констант и код в ответе так и так ломается на простейшем вводе `'a=" "'`. В общем случае следует избегать такой балет: строка -> объекты -> строка -> объект (избегать туда сюда прыгать между сериализованным видом и десериализованным без нужды ([посмотрите в конце ответа по ссылке](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/488513/23044)).

Comment: Вот [парсер](https://gist.github.com/zed/6a10c598c378de7d7f568868c95dad4e), который поддерживает списки и словари, не ограничивает вложенность и поддерживает произвольные строковые значения. Без части с рекурсией это [простой автомат](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Lo8R.png).

Comment: @jfs, очень крутой [парсер](https://gist.github.com/zed/6a10c598c378de7d7f568868c95dad4e) по-моему. Мне кажется стоит оформить это как отдельный вопрос+ответ - наверняка многим может пригодиться...

Comment: этот парсер и не там и не тут: он начал свою жизнь как
[конечный автомат](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82)
(то что на картинке, сгенерированной с помощью ragel, показано) чтобы
распознать ввод в ответе, но по дороге захотелось и вложенные
структуры поддерживать. В итоге получилось что-то напоминающее метод
рекурсивного спуска ([LL(1)-язык](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/LL-%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80))...

Comment: ... Если сразу задаться целью
поддерживать произвольные json (для определённости) значения, то можно
[парсер сгеренировать с помощью grako](https://gist.github.com/zed/73f8d6081e67626ca9ed7e2a8a493902) (или другим генератором
парсеров, которых много). Вот как [грамматика выглядит, которую он
распознаёт.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2j6Qc.png)

Comment: @jfs, жалко, что многие жаждущие (ищущие) не увидят этот пример парсера...

Answer (score 1):

```
globals().update(eval('dict(%s)' % "a=1 b=2 c=3".replace(' ', ',')))
print(a, b, c)
```

Comment: Добавьте в ваш ответ детальное описание решения проблемы или кода, чтобы пользователи могли быстрее понять ваш ответ.

Comment: ужасы: и `eval()` и манипуляция `globals()`. Если вы хотите переменные получить, то можно `exec("a=1 b=2 c=3".replace(' ', ';'))`. Если словарь: `d={}; exec("a=1 b=2 c=3".replace(' ', ';'), {}, d)` **Как `eval` так и `exec` следует избегать** -- есть [менее взрывоопасные альтернативы](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/635164/%d1%81%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%8c#comment897184_635169)