# Парсинг описания схемы, лексический, синтаксический анализ

Tags: c++, синтаксический-анализ, парсер

Здравствуйте. Есть примерно файл со след. описанием:

```
INPUTS: x1, x2, x3;
OUTPUTS: y;
ELEMENTS: e1, e5 = OR, e2 = AND, e3 = not, e4 = AND;
SCHEMA: e1(x1, x2), e2(x2, x3),
e3(e1, e2), y(e3);
DEFECT: e3 = 1, x1 = 0;
TEST: 101, 011, 100
```

Мне нужно спарсить этот текст, и получить его в виде списков, словарей. Т.е, нужно получить:

1. список inputs[x1,x2,x3]
2. список outputs[y]
3. словарь elements{e1:OR, e5:OR, e2:AND, e3:NOT ...},
4. schema {e1: [x1, x2], e2: [x2, x3], ...},
5. defect {e3:1, x1:0},
6. test [101,011,100]

Как это проще всего осуществить? Я написал простенький лексер, чтобы удалить все проблемы, и получать поочередно служебны слова, идентификаторы, и разделители, но вот дальше не знаю что писать. Начал писать для каждой директивы (inputs, outputs) свою функцию парсинга (в случае inputs, outputs она одинакова), но как то получается довольно много кода, в каждой функции идет тот же самый цикл до точки с запятой, в каждой функции проверяется разделители. Может есть какие библиотеки, или как то регулярными выражениями это все извлечь просто? Я не силен в лексерах, парсерах, поэтому спрашиваю у вас.

Comment: Вы пишете вручную или на lex/yacc?

Comment: Вот вам пример: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/452045/10105

Comment: @VladD вручную. Я смотрел на lex/yacc, но мне они показались сложны и непонятны. Для такой, вроде простой задачи, не хотелось привлекать таких гигантов. Но если есть хорошие примеры, то пожалуй, воспользуюсь

Comment: Ну, у вас лёгкая грамматика, так что особых проблем быть не должно, если делать вручную..

Comment: Здесь можно PEG парсер из EBNF грамматики   сгенерировать ([пример](https://gist.github.com/zed/73f8d6081e67626ca9ed7e2a8a493902)) или руками recursive descent parser написать ([пример для той же задачи](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/635164/%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B0-key1-value1-key2-value2-k#comment897350_635295))

Comment: @VladD граматика то легкая, но я не имею опыта работы с таким родом задач. Из-за чего у меня получается говнокодище с очень большим кол-вом if, else if, else.

Comment: @van9petryk: Ну, вроде ж не так всё ужасно? Может быть, вы переусложнили грамматику. Покажите, какая она у вас получилась.

Comment: написал примерную [EBNF](https://gist.github.com/zed/fa834138b97ff6cd01d90114536c6e0a#file-scheme-ebnf) для формата в вопросе([картинка](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6BoiN.png)). [Пример успешно распознаётся](https://gist.github.com/zed/fa834138b97ff6cd01d90114536c6e0a#file-parse_scheme_description-py) (если есть возможность, то стоит существующий формат использовать json, yaml, toml, etc).