# Python 3.6 - парсинг файла и заполнение массива

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, динамические-массивы

Добрый день! Пишу 2D игру на Python 3.6 и возникла проблема создания массива.
Python я начал изучать совсем недавно. Смысл такой - функция должна парсить файл карты и заполнять массив. Структура карты простая, в зависимости от символа другая функция загружает спрайт, например '=' - это кирпичная стена, но все это должно считываться из массива, который я пока не понял, как делать. Пример файла карты:

```
LevelsCount:2
LevelName:Name
LevelNum:1
LevelType:Green
{
==d=====================
=0000000000000000000000=
=0000000000000000000000=
=0000000000000000000000=
=0000000000000000000000=
=0000000000000000000000=
=0001111122211111000000=
=0000000000000000000000=
========================
}
```

Уровень из файла карты должен считываться в трехмерный (?) массив от "{" до "}", причем выборочно, если укажу '1' в параметр функции, то считываться только LevelNum:1. Каждая строка является новым элементом массива и каждый символ является элементом массива, чтобы при доступе получить, к примеру:

```
==d=====================
```

blocks[0][0] - '=' или blocks[0][2] - 'd', где [0] это номер строки, а [2] - номер символа в строке.
Вот функция, которую я не могу написать правильно:

```
def parse_levelpack(chapt, lvl):
    lvl_file = open('pack/levels/Chapter' + str(chapt) + '.mapf', 'r')
    y_block = -1
    x_block = -1
    global levelCount
    line = lvl_file.readline()
    while line:
        line = line.replace('\n', '')
        line = lvl_file.readline()
        if line.find('{') > -1:
            y_block = y_block + 1
            x_block = -1
            blocks_array[y_block].append([])
            lvl_file.readline()
            if not line == '}':
                lvl_file.readline()
                x_block = x_block + 1
                blocks_array[x_block].append([])
                blocks_array[y_block][x_block].append(line[x_block])
    lvl_file.close()
```

chapt - часть, добавляется к имени файла, lvl - чтобы из файла карты выбрать нужный уровень, например, LevelNum:1.

Comment: О, рогалик :) А как быть с тем, что карта не матрица? Нужно чем-то добивать оставшиеся ячейки?

Comment: @gil9red, добрый день! Оставшиеся ячейки, которые не совпадают по длине с нижними строчками? Это берет на себя функция, которая парсит уже массив. Да, рогалик :) Вдохновлен Legend of Zelda )) UPD: Сделал карту матрицей

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Парсер простой, поэтому думаю автор сам его допилит, а я покажу пример парсера локаций:

```
def fill_blocks(text_or_list):
    blocks = []

    if type(text_or_list) == str:
        line_list = text_or_list.splitlines()
    else:
        line_list = text_or_list

    for line in line_list:
        line = line.strip()
        if not line:
            continue

        row = [x for x in line]
        blocks.append(row)

    return blocks


def get_text_level_blocks(text):
    text_level_blocks = []

    start_block = False
    blocks_text = None

    for line in text.splitlines():
        line = line.strip()
        if not line:
            continue

        if line == '{':
            start_block = True
            blocks_text = []
            continue

        elif line == '}':
            start_block = False
            text_level_blocks.append(blocks_text)
            continue

        # Если не кирпич
        elif not line.startswith('='):
            continue

        # Дальше ищем символ стартового блока
        if not start_block:
            continue

        blocks_text.append(line)

    return text_level_blocks


if __name__ == '__main__':
    text = """\
==d=====================
=0000000000000000000000=
=0000000000000000000000=
=0000000000000000000000=
=0000000000000000000000=========
=000000000000000000000000000000=
=0001111122211111000000=========
=0000000000000000000000=
========================
"""
    blocks = fill_blocks(text)
    print(''.join(blocks[0]))
    print(blocks[0][0])
    print()

    many_level_text = """\
{
==d=====================
=0000000000000000000000=
=0000000000000000000000=
=0000000000000000000000=
=0000000000000000000000=========
=000000000000000000000000000000=
=0001111122211111000000=========
=0000000000000000000000=
========================
}
...
{
==d=====================
=0000000000000000000000=
=0000000000000000000000=
=0000000000000000000000=
=0000000000000000000000=
=0000000000000000000000=
=0001111122211111000000=
=0000000000000000000000=
========================
}  
"""

    text_level_blocks = get_text_level_blocks(many_level_text)
    print(len(text_level_blocks))

    level_block = text_level_blocks[0]
    blocks = fill_blocks(level_block)
    print(''.join(blocks[0]))
    print(blocks[0][0])
    print()

    all_levels_block = []

    for level_block in text_level_blocks:
        blocks = fill_blocks(level_block)
        all_levels_block.append(blocks)

    print(''.join(all_levels_block[0][4]))
    print(''.join(all_levels_block[1][4]))
    print(all_levels_block[0][0][2])
    print(all_levels_block[1][0][2])
```

Консоль:

```
==d=====================
=

2
==d=====================
=

=0000000000000000000000=========
=0000000000000000000000=
d
d
```

Comment: Ваш вариант идеален, спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

Чтобы найти все `{}` блоки в файле, можно регулярное выражение использовать:

```
import re
from pathlib import Path

blocks = re.findall("(?s){(.*)}", Path('chart.mapf').read_text())
```

Чтобы превратить каждый блок в двухмерный список:

```
blocks3D = [block.strip().splitlines() for block in blocks]
```

Для проверки: [`blocks3D[0][-3][9]`](https://ideone.com/pvFxdS) это символ расположенный в первом блоке, на третьей с конца строчке, на десятой позиции (`'2'`).

В этом случае строчки типом str представлены — неизменяемы. Если хочется по одному символу изменять, можно матрицу создать со списками вместо строк:

```
blocks3D = [list(map(list, block.strip().splitlines())) for block in blocks]
```

Comment: Регулярки, генераторы списков и функциональщина рулят :)

Comment: @WLion забыл упомянуть: если это делается не в образовательных целях, то лучше существующий формат файла с доступными парсерами использовать типа json, toml, yaml — что вам больше приглянется в вашем конкретном случае.

Comment: @jfs, это делается в целях... хобби, ну и изучаю сам Python, так сказать, не хочу знать один лишь C# )) Была даже идея с xml, но решил сделать простой текстовый файл.

Comment: @WLion если хобби, попробуйте PEG-парсер сгенерировать для вашего формата из EBNF нотации, с помощью [tatsu (grako)](https://github.com/neogeny/TatSu/blob/master/README.rst) или руками с помощью pyparsing, PLY. [Пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/635164/%d1%81%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b0-key1-value1-key2-value2-k/635295#comment897918_635295)