# Автоматический расчет разницы двух дат в днях

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-orm

Имеется следующая модель:

```
 class Product(models.Model):
     data_start = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
     data_end = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
     days_left = models.IntegerField(null=True)

     def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
         data_end = self.data_end
         data_start = self.data_start
         d1 = datetime.strptime(str(data_end), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S+%f:00")
         d2 = datetime.strptime(str(data_start), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S+%f:00") 
         self.days_left = abs((d2 - d1).days)
         super(Product, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Расчитываю количество дней между датами и сохраняю в БД. Но, стоит задача обновлять, сколько осталось дней, когда сегодняшний день приближается к конечной дате. Как такое можно реализовать? Спасибо.

Python 3.5.3, Django 1.11

Comment: 1- На лету [с помощью @property можно значение получить](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17683916/4279). 2- не нужно date  в строку превращать, чтобы тут же назад в date превратить. Избегайте [йо-йо код](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/488513/23044)

Comment: Обновлять по какому событию? По запросу пользователя, или просто в  фоне? Если в фоне - можно сделать в том числе через cron... Если по запросу пользователя - всё еще проще.

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич, скорее в фоне. Есть интерфейс к БД.
cron, как вариант

Comment: То есть у Вас сервер генерирует некие события, или все таки говорит, что событие настало/было по запросу? Разница именно в этом :) Если нет прямой необходимости генерировать сигнал на внешний источник (как то будильник) - запись в БД в определенное время не обязательна.

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич, сервер ничего не генерирует) Только при запросе отдаются данные из БД, с поддержкой функций CRUD.
Просто сохраняются в БД две даты, в поле "Осталось дней" высчитывается разница в днях. Если заходим на следующий день, то это поле пересчитывается относительно сегодняшней и конечной даты. Получается, нужно писать крон, который каждый день этим будет заниматься? Или есть другой вариант?

Comment: Зачем писать то, что написано в БД, если можно написать, что произошло/не произошло уже по факту? Допустим, человек зашел, ему надо отобразить сколько дней осталось до события, ну так и посчитайте сколько осталось... Зачем для этого апдейтить базу в фоне до его захода - вот в чем вопрос. Посчитать в момент запроса гораздо быстрее и правильнее, чем это делать каждый день, например...

Comment: Можно ведь и фильтровать.. Допустим за 7 дней до события нужно писать, что до события еще ой как далеко... Так и пишем if days_to_event>7:     user_message_for_event = u'До события %s еще очень далеко' % event.name Как то так...