# Как декодировать строку возвращаемую lxml.etree tostring?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Функция tostring из lxml.etree вернула `<&#1057;&#1074;&#1051;&#1080;&#1094;&#1077;&#1085;&#1079;&#1080;&#1103; &#1053;&#1086;&#1084;&#1051;&#1080;&#1094;="&#x420;&#x421;&#x41D;` Как теперь перевести в нормальный вид? Я уже разные кодировки в decod передавал. Ни какая не помогла.

Comment: что по вашему lxml.etree `tostring()` возвращает? Почему вы думаете, что эту строку необходимо декодировать? Если вы не хотели xml получить, то что вы вместо этого из XML tree хотите сгенерировать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"tostring из lxml.etree" вернула вам [html escape sequences](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-escapes) в формате NCRs, в котором символ представлен в виде последовательности из `&#` и [десятичного числа, представляющего его позицию в таблице символов Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point). Если под "нормальным видом" вы подразумеваете строку python, то самый просто способ - это воспользоваться функцией [unescape модуля html](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.html#html.unescape):

```
import html

s = '&#1057;&#1074;&#1051;&#1080;&#1094;&#1077;&#1085;&#1079;...'

print(html.unescape(s))
```

Comment: Вы хоть объясните топикстартеру что тут за кодировки

Comment: @tutankhamun он не спрашивал, что это за кодировки, его интересует только "как перевести в нормальный вид".

Comment: если автору не нужен xml, то вместо `tostring()` на xml tree объекте, можно прочитать значения отдельных атрибутов e.g.: `el.text`. А то получается, что сперва `tostring()` старательно всё экранирует, а затем `html.unescape` обратную работу делает. Подобный код иногда называют Йо-йо кодом (см. [ссылки в конце ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/488513/23044))¶ Возможен ещё вариант, что автору просто следует явно кодировку указать: `lxml.etree.tostring(tree, encoding='utf-8', xml_declaration=True)`, чтобы избежать NCR.