# как в питоне в переменную добавить текущую дату?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

Есть переменная:

```
date = 2018-03-21T14:35:18.000Z
```

Необходимо посчитать сколько дней прошло с этого момента. Я понимаю, что в mysql есть NOW, но каждый раз запрашивать БД... Не хотелось бы...

Comment: Переменная откуда берётся?

Comment: `datetime.now()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Время у вас в UTC, поэтому вычитать из `datetime.now()`, которое местное время возвращает это неправильно в большинстве часовых зон.

Простой способ это использовать `datetime.utcnow()` чтобы найти сколько полных дней прошло с указанного UTC времени (в rfc 3339 формате):

```
import datetime as DT

now = DT.datetime.utcnow()
then = DT.datetime.strptime('2018-03-21T14:35:18.000Z', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')
print((now - then).days) # whole number of days between two dates
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/brython-dev/brython/3.4.0/www/src/brython.js"></script><script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/brython-dev/brython/3.4.0/www/src/brython_stdlib.js"></script><body onload="brython()"><script type="text/python">
import datetime as DT
from browser import document

@document["mybutton"].bind("click") 
def on_click(event):
    time_string = document["time"].value
    then = DT.datetime.strptime(time_string, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')
    days = (DT.datetime.utcnow() - then) // DT.timedelta(1) 
    print(f"{time_string} -> {days} day(s)")
</script><label for="time">Тогда: </label><input id="time" value="2018-03-21T14:35:18.000Z"> <button id="mybutton">Запустить</button></body>
```

На всякий случай: проверьте что `isinstance(date, str)` у вас на входе (из вопроса не ясно), если это не так, то НЕ следует str вызывать. Если `date` у вас уже `datetime` объект (или схожее), то следует методами этого объекта пользоваться вместо этого. Избегайте Yo-Yo код (см. [ссылки в конце ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/488513/23044)).

Answer (score 1):

Можно воспользоваться модулем datetime

```
from datetime import datetime
last_day =datetime.strptime('2018-03-21T14:35:18.000Z', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.000Z')
now = datetime.now()
delta = last_day - now
```

Comment: Только наоборот: ``delta = now - last_day``

Comment: это неправильно, если местное время не совпадает с UTC