# Посчитать дни с текущей даты

Tags: python, дата

Есть переменная, которая хранит в себе дату в виде:

```
created = peewee.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
```

> 2018-04-18 15:03:59.98847

Как вычесть сколько дней прошло с этой даты, пример вывода ниже:

> 2018-04-18 15:03:59 (1 день)

Comment: у вас сложности получить дату как datetime объект или не знаете что можно `a - b` написать или не знаете как количество дней из timedelta получить? (пренебрегая часовыми зонами)

Comment: как количество дней из timedelta получить

Comment: https://python-scripts.com/datetime-time-python

Comment: связанный вопрос [как в питоне в переменную добавить текущую дату?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/803008/23044)

Comment: Вроде бы понял, извиняюсь, благодарю

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Через `timedelta`:

```
import datetime as DT
...
print((DT.datetime.now() - created).days)
```

Comment: Большое спасибо